# Div Outline visible in IE/Edge even though div is hidden

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have a text engine that generates HTML/CSS. Below is some text that it generated.

```css
#text516 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 197px;
  top: 168px;
  width: 201px;
  height: 81px;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: rgb(0, 120, 228);
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-width: thin;
  outline-color: rgb(0, 120, 228);
}

span.text516Font1 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  color: #010101;
}
```

```html
<div id="text516" style="width: 201px; height: 81px;">
  <a tabindex="1" id="text516anc" style="display:block;height:0px;width:0px;"></a>
  <table style="border-collapse:collapse;top:0px;position:absolute; border-spacing:0; width:100%; height:100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="position: absolute;top:0px;left:0px;box-sizing:border-box;width:100%;vertical-align:top;height:100%;padding:5px">
          <div style="height:100%;width:100%;overflow-y:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;">

            <p style="margin-left:0px;text-indent:0px;line-height:1.350;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;text-align:left;" dbg_tag_42="" leglh="1.409" dbg_tag_34.1a="">
              <span class="text516Font1" style="position:relative;top:-2px;" dbg_tag_95="">hi my name is matthew and I like pie.
    </span></p>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Also, [here is a JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/gdb4docb/27/) to see the problem ( Only in IE/Edge )

There are a few things I can do to fix this problem, such as removing the style attribute from the span encapsulating the text. I can also remove the table elements and leave just the p tag, but when left as it is above, the outline always shows regardless of the fact that the outer div is set to be hidden. Is this a bug with the browser, or is it some HTML functionality that I am missing?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430485/ie-css-bug-table-border-showing-div-with-visibility-hidden-position-absolute

Comment: I dont have explorer on my linux
what if you use outline property, does that not help you?

Comment: @fabio_MO Thank you for the link. That was helpful!

Comment: @Matthewmallimo You are welcome :)